# How to select all from a dropdown using ASP/JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a piece of software that I am working on that allows you to select locations and this shows on a map. I want to add functionality to select all the locations with a button and show the information on the map.

I'm new to coding and therefore haven't really written any code. I have been searching the web but to no avail which is why I came to ask you lovely people on here.

Any advice or links you provide will be greatly appreciated.

function checkAddAllName(mode){

```
    var Name = document.getElementById('select_'+mode+'_ID').options[document.getElementById('select_'+mode+'_ID').selectedIndex].text;
    var Name = document.getElementById('select_'+mode+'_ID').options[document.getElementById('select_'+mode+'_ID').selectedIndex].value;

    var errorCount = 0;
    var Name = 0;
    var allStations = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i=0; i<allNames.length; i++){
        if (allNames[i].id.substring(0,10) == 'StationNo_'){
            var splitID = allNames[i].id.split("_");
                if (splitID[1] == mode){
                    if (allNames[i].value == addedNameNo){
                        errorCount = 1;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    if (errorCount == 0){
        addNAme(mode);
    } else {
        alert(addedName+' has already been added!');
    }
```

}

Comment: show us what you have so far, like the drop down html.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can do that as it's a work project and I wouldn't be allowed to copy and paste the code into here.

Comment: @CodingNewbie your request is too generic, you would have to provide an example of what you have, even if not exact if you want this site to be of much help. Posting parts of code should not compromise your projects, just be sure to remove any sensitive information and never post a full page of code or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off doing this using a library like jQuery. It'll take you some time in the beginning to learn, but it'll pay off for the rest of your web programming days.

Assuming your locations are an unordered list of checkboxes like:

```
<ul id='listId'>
   <li><input type="checkbox value="London">London</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox value="Paris">Paris</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</li>
</ul>
<button id="selectAll">Select all</button>
```

In jQuery you'd do something like:

```
$('button#selectAll').on("click",function(){
  $('ul#listId > li > input').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean ordinary single selection drop down like this:

```
<select id="ddlSelectCountry" onchange="SelectCountry(this);">
    <option value="">Please select..</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>
```

You can have such button to auto select all non empty items:

```
<button type="button" onclick="SelectAll('ddlSelectCountry');">Select All</button>​
```

And the JavaScript for that would be:

```
function SelectAll(strDropDownId) {
    var oDDL = document.getElementById(strDropDownId);
    if (!oDDL) {
        alert("No such element: " + strDropDownId);
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < oDDL.options.length; i++) {
        if (oDDL.options[i].value.length > 0) {
            oDDL.selectedIndex = i;
            if (oDDL.change)
                oDDL.change();
            else if (oDDL.onchange)
                oDDL.onchange();
        }
    }
}
```

Using jQuery the code can be greatly reduced in length and made more elegant, but that's your choice.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/GHEsA/).

Comment: Thalis Kalfigkopoulos and @Shadow Wizard - Thank you for your efforts to offer code to help me with this issue. I am unfortunately not using jQuery and it isn't a planned language to use. The list I am working with is a standard list with a single add button and I need to add functionality for add all. The program was written using ASP/HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: @CodingNewbie the code I gave is pure JavaScript, no library needed. It give you a way to auto select all drop down items with single button click but it also require some basic skill in JavaScript from your side. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am just having a look at your code now and seeing how I can get it to work.

Comment: This is my code above in the original post, I have taken out some of the names as I don't want to give away any details so the code will look a little odd. It will currently add one from the list but I need it to add all.

Comment: Sorry but the code you posted is not helping a bit. All it's doing is checking if some given text already exists as value of any input element and if not call function called `addName`. What you asked for is totally different thing.

Comment: Ok, it's a complex system that I only inherited this week so it's taking some time for me to read through and learn what everything does. I have managed to get a new button on the page and it adds one location but I need it to add them all.